# How to stop Vuforia Behaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have three scenes in my project.

First one is just a Main Menu.

Second one is a Virtual Reality Scene using GoogleVR

Third one is a AR Scene using vuforia.

Not sure why, but when I started VR Scene (Not AR), vuforia behaviour is loaded too and it changed my field of view.

There is a way to prevent vuforia to start when app is loaded and just start when I load AR Scene?

I tried this but not worked. This stopped the camera instance, but not vuforia behaviour.

```
public void stopAR(){
    if (Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.IsActive()) {
        Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.Deinit ();
        Vuforia.CameraDevice.Instance.Stop ();
        Debug.Log ("AR Stopped");
    }
}
```

Comment: It means you have the Vuforia component in the scene. It won't load if no there, your main menu is proof. The GoogleVR will also change your FOV, as it only works with one setting.So maybe the changing come from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answare. What you mean about Vuforia component? In my AR scene, I have ARCamera, but in MainMenu scene and VR Scene I just have Main Camera. I think it load because in my player settings I have Augmented Reality checked. But this is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED]
I followed this to solve this problem:

On Main Camera where I do not want Vuforia to start, add VuforiaBehavious script

Uncheck it

Done.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I found a way to disable this behaviour entirely following [this example](https://forum.unity.com/threads/use-ar-camera-vuforia-core-in-individual-scene-not-entire-project.498489/).

You just add this to a gameobject in your FIRST scene and make sure it executes before anything else (e.g. through the script execution order). It unsubscribes the event method call from the [SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html) to the [VuforiaRuntime](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/unity/classVuforia_1_1VuforiaRuntime.html) singleton that adds the behaviour(s) to every main camera in every scene. Once this is done, it should never do this again.

**Tested version for Unity 2017.3.1p4**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;

public class StopAutoAddVuforia : MonoBehaviour
{
     private void Awake() {
         // https://forum.unity.com/threads/use-ar-camera-vuforia-core-in-individual-scene-not-entire-project.498489/
         try {
             EventInfo evSceneLoaded = typeof(SceneManager).GetEvent("sceneLoaded");
             Type tDelegate = evSceneLoaded.EventHandlerType;

             MethodInfo attachHandler = typeof(Vuforia.VuforiaRuntime).GetMethod("AttachVuforiaToMainCamera", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

             Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(tDelegate, attachHandler);
             SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= d as UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction<Scene, LoadSceneMode>;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             Debug.LogWarning("Cant remove the AttachVuforiaToMainCamera action. Execption:" + e.Message);
         }

         Destroy(this);
     }
 }
```

**Tested version for Unity 2018.2.4f1**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;

 public class StopAutoAddVuforia : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private void Awake() {
         // https://forum.unity.com/threads/use-ar-camera-vuforia-core-in-individual-scene-not-entire-project.498489/
         try {
             EventInfo evSceneLoaded = typeof(SceneManager).GetEvent("sceneLoaded");
             Type tDelegate = evSceneLoaded.EventHandlerType;

             MethodInfo attachHandler = typeof(Vuforia.VuforiaRuntime).GetMethod("AttachVuforiaToMainCamera", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

             Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction<Scene, LoadSceneMode>), Vuforia.VuforiaRuntime.Instance, attachHandler);
             SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= d as UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction<Scene, LoadSceneMode>;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             Debug.LogError("Cant remove the AttachVuforiaToMainCamera action. Exception " + e.Message);
         }

         Destroy(this);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class NoAR : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera camera;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if(camera.enabled)
            if (camera.GetComponent<VuforiaBehaviour>() != null)
                camera.GetComponent<VuforiaBehaviour>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically when the camera is on you can see a Vuforia Behaviour  sprite so I decide to set the sprite enabled = false  , so you can able to use your main camera without AR camera . Does it work for u ????

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] You can just enable/disable the Vuforia camera using the **VuforiaBehavior** component.

```
void StartCamera () {
    vuforiaBehavior.enabled = true;
}

void StopCamera () {
    vuforiaBehavior.enabled = false;
}
```